# Difference between verb against used to verb+ing

Tags: american-english

Voughan advanced CD 2 he is using verbs like:

> *he used to living..* etc...

What is the difference between such use and "*he used to live?*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you misread/type that? Would you mind providing us the link/source? Because...

I doubt it should be...

> ***'He's*** used to living....*

It then makes sense. A sentence from [The Telegram](http://www.telegram.com/article/20140623/NEWS/306239850/0)

> Brad said he's lived on sailboats the past few years, so ***he's used to living*** in small quarters.

This simply means that he is habituated of living in that place with little space.

On the other hand, *used to live* is an all different thing. [*Used to*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/used-to) here is used to talk about something that happened in the past. We can think about the sentence using this like...

> *He used to live in Australia*

This means, for that particular period, he lived in Australia.